Postgres Query using concat and LIKE
I have a Postgres table with two columns (in fact it has many more), a numeric column named TicketId and a text column named Tags.  Here are three sample rows of data:
TicketId   Tags
1234       apple,apple_pie,apricot,peach,rhubarb_crumbs,rhubarb
5678       apple,apricot,peach,rhubarb_crumbs,rhubarb,wheat
9999       rhubarb,turnips,whey

FYI, the front-end website is a out of the box product that I have very little control over. As data is saved, keywords are extracted and saved as Tags, thus the need to query the tag column.  The system automatically puts the comma in between each tag.
When the table is created, the column is text.
Tags  text  not null,
In the above example, I only want to return rows with 'rhubarb'.  I don't want any rows with rhubarb_crumbs.
I'm trying to execute this query to only pull rows where Tags contains 'rhubarb'. Note that when 'rhubarb' appears at the front of the string there is no leading comma and when 'rhubarb' appears at the end of the string there is no trailing comma.
SELECT TicketId, ',' || Tags || ',' AS Tags
FROM [tablename]
WHERE ',' || Tags || ',' LIKE '%,rhubarb,%'

The query runs, but only returns the 2nd row. The output looks like this.  Note the comma in the first and last positions of the text field:
TicketId   Tags
5678       ,apple,apricot,peach,rhubarb_crumbs,rhubarb,wheat,

Is it possible to put delimiters on the ends of a text field and query it?
I could do the following query
WHERE Tags LIKE '%rhubarb%'
   OR Tags LIKE 'rhubarb,%'
   OR Tags LIKE '%,rhubarb'

to pull all three rows, but if I have a request for multiple ingredients, then the WHERE LIKE statement becomes very cumbersome.  I'm sure there are performance issues for each additional LIKE statement within the query.
Thus the desire to somehow put a leading and trailing comma around the Tags column when I run the query.
I could do a SELECT FROM .. INSERT INTO ... a temporary table to get the commas around the Tags column, but that seems like a LOT of work to me for something that should be very simple.
Thank you!!!


There are commas there because you put them there: ',' || Tags || ','.  2) Why not ILIKE '%rhubarb%': a) ILIKE will take care of case sensitivity. 2) You aren't searching for commas just rhubarb.  FYI, this why you are not getting the row with ,rhubarb_crumbs, rhubarb. 3) What is it you want to do with output. Add information as text update to question text.


Your query works as you want. The issue is not reproducible.

Can't reproduce this issue.  Both rows are returned for me.  Please share a full reproduction case, showing the creating and population of the table.

Perhaps, Tags followed by space. For example ,rhubarb_crumbs,rhubarb  

Slightly off-topic but still related: Why do you store multiple values in a single column? That's a recipe for problems in a relational database.

Please fix your question. As it stands, its contradictory, the query would return both rows. Also, disclose your version of Postgres, and let us know whether fixing your broken table design is an option.

FYI, I edited my question to better answer all responses.

Just use begin line (^) and end line ($) match symbols

^ matches at the beginning of the string
$ matches at the end of the string

in your example, if the tag field starts with the word you need to find, the query will not work. And if the tag field contains only the word you need to find, the query will also not work.
pattern(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)
select 'apple,apple_pie,apricot,peach,rhubarb_crumbs,rhubarb' ~ '(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t

select 'apple,apple_pie,apricot,peach,rhubarb_crumbs,rhubarb,test2' ~ '(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t

select 'rhubarb,asdfasdf' ~ '(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t

select 'rhubarb' ~ '(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)';
 ?column?
----------
 t


SELECT TicketId FROM [tablename] WHERE Tags ~ '(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)'

HI arutar, I am not able to make your query work.

@Brian SELECT TicketId FROM [tablename] WHERE Tags ~ '(^|,)rhubarb(,|$)'

Thank you, arutar, that works perfectly!
